How to get conda to install pytorch-gpu rather than pytorch-cpu Ubuntu cuda 11.4
I've combed through all of the similar questions but to no avail. I have an older GPU that I'm trying to get to work with CUDA and pytorch. For some reason, I can't get conda to install pytorch gpu. No matter what I do, it tries to install the cpu version of pytorch.
I build my conda like this - miniconda

conda create --name tortoise python=3.9 numba inflect

I need to force a specific version of CUDA 11.4.
conda install pytorch=1.11.0 torchvision=0.12 torchaudio=0.11 cudatoolkit=11.4 -c pytorch -c nvidia

Someone said that torchvision and torchaudio could cause the cpu version to be installed.
conda install pytorch=1.11.0 cudatoolkit=11.4 -c pytorch -c nvidia

Regardless of what I do, it tries to install the cpu version of pytorch.

So what it is that is determining that the cpu version should be installed. I have a GPU in this box.

conda info


Can you show the output of conda info?

Looks like the gpu is correctly detected by conda, but looking at the available files in the pytorch channel, I think there is no version for cuda version 11.4. Can you try a different cuda version, e.g. conda install pytorch=1.11.0 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch -c nvidia

That worked. Do you want to make that the answer?
Because I'm trying to learn to fish, how did you figure this out that cuda wasn't available in 11.4?

Posted it as an answer with an explanation on how you can check available versions

Since the virtual package __cuda==11.4 is present, conda should be able to install the gpu accelerated versions of pytorch. The next thing to check is available cuda versions. You can use conda search for that like so:
conda search -c pytorch pytorch==1.11
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
pytorch                       1.11.0    py3.10_cpu_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.10_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.10_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.10_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.10_cuda11.5_cudnn8.3.2_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0     py3.7_cpu_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.7_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.7_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.7_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.7_cuda11.5_cudnn8.3.2_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0     py3.8_cpu_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.8_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.8_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.8_cuda11.5_cudnn8.3.2_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0     py3.9_cpu_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.9_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.9_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.9_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0  pytorch
pytorch                       1.11.0 py3.9_cuda11.5_cudnn8.3.2_0  pytorch

Note that for python 3.9, which you have, there are only cuda10.2, cuda11.1, cuda11.3 and cuda11.5 available.
So by forcing cudatoolkit=11.4, conda cannot find a suitable pytorch gpu version and installs a cpu only variant. Since you driver/graphics card are only capable up to cuda 11.4, your best option is probably to use 11.3:
conda install pytorch=1.11.0 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch -c nvidia

